# How to access contents of pop up window of a new tab in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, popupwindow

I have developed a website and set as a google chrome extension.What I need is that when i install my extension a pop up window should be opened on a new window asking username and password and has to be stored this username in a local storage that should be accessible in chrome extension.How can I do that please help me.
Here is my manifest.json

```
   {
"name": "Calpine Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Log on to calpinemate",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon_128.png"
},
"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Calpine Extension",
    "default_icon": "calpine_not_logged_in.png" 

},
"permissions": [

   "*://blog.calpinetech.com/test/index.php",
    "alarms",
    "notifications"
 ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
  "/icon_128.png"]

 }
```

here is my code for pop up in background.js

```
chrome.windows.create({url : "test.html"});
```

This i have written inside chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener().

This is my test.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function log(){
            var uname=document.getElementById('name');
            alert(uname);
            //window.localStorage.setItem('uname', $("input[type='username']").val());
            //alert(localStorage.uname);
        }
    </script>
</head>
 <body>
<form name="userinfo" id="userinfo">
      username : 
      <input id="name" type="text" name="username"/><br><br>
      password :
      <input type="password" name="password"/><br><br>
       <input type="button" value="Log In" onClick="log()"/>
     </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Now what I need is that when the user enables my extension  a popup window must be opened in a new window asking username and password.When he enters the username and password ,the username must be stored in a localstorage which is accessible from chrome extension.How can I do it?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use This in any of the js file that you have added as script.

```
//open new tab for installation after extension is added to chrome 
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (install) {
//code for installation
chrome.windows.create({ 'url': chrome.extension.getURL('test.html') }, function (tab) {
    //write the code to do something when tab is created on install()
});
});
```

In js code, write bind event on click of log in button.

for setting localstorage,You can use.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('uname', $("input[type='username']").val());
window.localStorage.setItem('passwrod', $("input[type='password']").val());
```

And to get them,

```
window.localStorage.getItem('uname');
window.localStorage.getItem('passwrod');
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I would check it

Comment: HI but i need to create the popup in a new window.and not a new tab

Comment: this is not working.even localStorage.uname is not displayed when I tried to alert it.

Comment: OK.I will update my code.NO ERROR.but alert (uname) is not working

Comment: Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".  this is the error shown

Comment: Can anyone help me.Can't figure out what is the problem

Comment: have you added this `"permissions": ["tabs", "https://*.google.com/*","http://*.google.com/*","http://*/ ","https://*/ ","storage"],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",`